# How to compare UINT (not uint64 or uint32) with string

Tags: rest, go

I have written following code and want to check if typed URL in REST API is same with user_id in header to grant the access or return a failure message, but there is following error:

"invalid operation: userId != vars["user_id"] (mismatched types uint and string)"

func UserIdAutentication(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request)  {

```
id := r.Context().Value("user").(uint)

vars:=mux.Vars(r)

if userId != vars["user_id"] {
    response := u.Message(false, "User not Autorized to fetch other users data")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    u.Respond(w, response)
    return
} else {
    return
}
```

}

Comment: [Convert the string to a `uint`](https://godoc.org/strconv#ParseUint) and compare the `uint`s.

Comment: it's not clear from the code what type ``userId`` is...maybe you mean the ``id`` variable?   Assuming that is the case then don't do a type assertion to force it to uint.  Whatever type ``r.Context().Value("user")`` is convert it to the same as ``vars["user_id"]``.  Not enough detail for a proper answer, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You should convert `user_id` to `uint` before compare to another unit.

```golang
id := r.Context().Value("user").(uint)
vars:=mux.Vars(r)

userID, err := strconv.ParseUint(vars["user_id"], 0, 64)

if err != nil {
    // Do something with eror
}

if userId!=uint(userID){
    response := u.Message(false, "User not Autorized to fetch other users data")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    u.Respond(w, response)
    return
}else {
    return
}
```